# multi-statement table-valued function calculate/display percentages

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
 UserName  Question_ID  Answer
  Tom       Q001           D
  Wendy     Q009           A
  Eddy      Q089           C
  David     Q001           C
  Eve       Q001           D
  Paul      Q001           A
  Sam       Q001           B
  Tom       Q002           B
  Tom       Q003           C
```

I want to create multi statement tabled valued function.

Let Question_id as input, I want to create table shows question_id, answer, number of answers, and percentages of answers

For example (input: Question_id = Q001)

The output will be

```
  Question_ID Answer Total Percentage
    Q001          A      1       20
    Q001          B      1       20
    Q001          C      1       20
    Q001          D      2       40
```

I have created a function sample below:

```
create function [dbo].[QuestionFrequency]
(
@question_id varchar(10)    
)

Returns @frequency table (question_id varchar(10), answer varchar(10))
As 
begin

insert @frequency (question_id, answer)
select question_Id, Answer from questions where @question_id = Question_id
return 
end
```

Currently this code doesn't display anything to me?

I have this to calculate percentages too, but my question is, how to get user input? to run the functions?

THIS IS THE CODE:

create table [online_questionaire] 
(  username nchar(10)  null ,
 question_id nchar(20)  null ,
 answer nchar(20)  null , )

insert into online_questionaire (username, question_id, answer)
values
('tom', 'q001' ,'d'),
('wendy', 'q09' ,'a'),
('eddy', 'q089' ,'c'),
('david', 'q001' ,'c'),
('eve', 'q001' ,'d'),
('paul', 'q001' ,'a'),
('sam', 'q001' ,'b');
 GO

create function [dbo].[QuestionFrequency]
    (
          @question_id varchar(10)
    )

```
Returns @frequency table (question_id varchar(10), answer varchar(10))
As 
begin

insert @frequency (question_id, answer)
select question_Id, Answer from online_questionaire where @question_id = Question_id
return 
end
```

Go
    select
    q.Question_ID, q.Answer,
    count(*) as Total,
    count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from online_questionaire as t where t.Question_ID = @question_id) as [Percentage]
from online_questionaire as q
where q.Question_ID= @question_id
group by q.Question_ID, q.Answer

DECLARE @Question_ID VARCHAR(64) = 'Q001'

SELECT *
FROM QuestionFrequency(@Question_ID) AS qf

Comment: you can use for stored proc then apply your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to invoke the Table-valued function you have above:

```
DECLARE @Question_ID VARCHAR(64) = 'Q001'

SELECT *
FROM QuestionFrequency(@Question_ID) AS qf
```

Comment: i get an error message Must declare the scalar variable "@Question_ID".
 
refering to     count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from online_questionaire as t where t.Question_ID = @question_id) as [Percentage]

Comment: Looking back at your modified question I am kind of confused at what you are really trying to accomplish.  I thought you were just looking for how to call the table valued function. It looks like you are trying to use "@question_id" in the line "from online_questionaire as t where t.Question_ID = @question_id" before the variable is declared.  Move my DECLARE "@Question_ID" stuff right before the line "select q.Question_ID, q.Answer, count() as Total, ".